# How can I regulate 220 Vac fans with a microcontroller?

Tags: circuit-design, ac, dimmer, load-regulation

I need to control some 220 Vac fans. The fans are [PAPST 4650N](https://docs.rs-online.com/a59f/A700000008447585.pdf) and I would like to control the speed using a simple MCU like an ATmega328P.

I'm not interested in fine speed control, I only need to have a sort of ramp, such as 20/40/60/80/100%.

As my first attempt I've used [these](https://www.futurashop.it/image/cache/catalog/data/scatole%20di%20montaggio/2846-1CHDIMMERMOD/2846-1CHDIMMERMOD-600x600.jpg) AC dimmer modules that use [this circuit](https://www.futurashop.it/image/catalog/data/scatole%20di%20montaggio/2846-1CHDIMMERMOD/2846-1CHDIMMERMOD_sch2.jpg), but it's not working at all. It seems that the phase-angle technique is not suitable at all with AC fans.

I'm looking for an easy and affordable solution. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The rotational speed of the fan you specified is controlled by the line frequency, i.e., 50 Hz. You are better off using a DC fan if you want to control rotational speed.

Comment: It's not possible, i have to use these AC fans!

Comment: Do you need to control the fans or the amount of air flow? If the latter then you could use some sort of motorised shutter.

Comment: Just a note if looking for an "unusual" fan with "control input"; beware "PWM" often refers to "tach output", not a speed input.  The datasheet details of many fans is lackluster at best and it'll behoove the reader to ensure the selected fan *actually has* the desired features before ordering.  If the datasheet isn't explicit, ask the distributor or manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

As phase control hasn't worked with the fans you have, it is most likely they are using induction motors.

Induction motors are a low-cost option, suited to simple mass-market applications like fans. However, their rotational speed is a function of the applied voltage and its frequency, more so the latter.

Therefore you would need a Variable Frequency Drive (VFD), also called an inverter. These typically use PWM control of a DC supply to produce the AC voltage waveforms using frequency synthesis, though PDM can be used.

This is [explained in detail here and illustrated below](https://www.kebamerica.com/blog/pulse-width-modulation-in-vfds/). In short though, you'd need an off-the shelf VFD, which is far from cheap, or to make your own.

Although the principles in making your own are simple, the parts aren't and your resultant high-voltage electronics board would almost certainly need safety approval.

You don't detail your situation here but I'd imagine (guess) that the VFD parts and labour costs outweigh, by some way, the parts and labour costs of choosing a different fan and refitting field installations. After all, those same installations would have needed the VFD mounted, wired in and fitted.

[image]

Comment: There are little DIN rail mount 1/4 hp VFDs out there for <$200 but that's still far more expensive than buying a equivalent fan with PWM input, of which I am finding several.

Comment: @vir, I'd written the final paragraph backwards, fixed now. Dunno if that affects your comment...

Comment: No, no, I agree with you completely.  There's not a great argument for dropping $200 on a controller for a $50 fan when perfectly suitable $50 fans with the required control inputs already exist.  But who knows, it might take 5 hours of labor to go in and replace it.